# Can I get the list of friends who like my feed

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

Can I get the list of friends who like my feed
I wanna get the friends list who like my feed. So I execute this query.
But I get the empty result.
What shouuld I modify to get thefriends list who like my feed.

```
queries: {
    likeFriend: 'select user_id from like where post_id in (select post_id from stream where source_id = me())',
    notLikeFriend: 'select uid, name, sex from user where uid in (select user_id from #likeFriend)'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

does your app have the read_stream permission?
be sure you have this as stated here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/